# Resize method of generic type array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am trying to create a Resize method for an Array, and have to use a generic array. I have the constructor as follows:

```
public ArrayLists (Class <T[]> a) { 
    array = (T[])Array.newInstance(a, DEFAULT_SIZE);
}
```

Then if the end user wants to resize the array to augmennt or decrease it, I have the Resize method, in which I want to create a new `temp` array with the passed in size and have the old array point to the temp. I can't figure out how to create the temp array however. So far I have:

```
public void Resize (double tempSize) {
    //create the temp array of size tempSize  
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, 0, size);
    array = temp;
}//end resize
```

I have tried something similar to what I had in the constructor with the `Array.newInstance` but I can only do that by having another parameter of `Class<T[]>` and then with that I am unable to reassign `array` to `temp`. And I can't just create an array of type generic because java doesn't like that.

This might be a little easier but my main problem is when testing it I need to create arrays of at least 2 different types to test... for instance

```
ArrayLists<String> list = new ArrayLists<>(String[].class);
ArrayLists<Random> list1 = new ArrayLists<>(Random[].class);
```

and then calling `list.Resize(20);` for example. Any suggestions??

### EDIT QUESTION

I am having issues implementing the resize method now. I created 2 arrays:

```
ArrayLists<String> list = new ArrayLists<>(String[].class);
ArrayLists<Random> list1 = new ArrayLists<>(Random[].class);
```

and also have this default constructor:

```
public ArrayLists(){
    this.size = DEFAULT_SIZE;
}//end cons
```

which (i think) should be enough to initialize the arrays with a default size of "10." But whenever I test it it is showing me that the original size of both list and list1 is 0 and will not let me resize them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should pass a `Class<T>`, and not a `Class<T[]>`. That method will create an array `T[][]`. So, change your constructor to:

```
public ArrayLists (Class <T> a) { 
    array = (T[])Array.newInstance(a, DEFAULT_SIZE);
}
```

And pass `String.class` instead of `String[].class`.

Now, the issue that you are having can be solved by using [`Class#getComponentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType%28%29) method. That will get you the component type `Class<T>` of the array:

```
// Why the type of tempSize is double? It should be `int`
public void resize (int tempSize) {
    //create the temp array of size tempSize  
    T[] temp = (T[]) Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), 
                                       tempSize);
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, 0, tempSize);
    array = temp;
}
```

Comment: I had tempSize as a double becasue in an insert method I have I incremented the size of it by 20%, which would have given a double. Buuut I just realized that by doing so wouldn't give a clear definition of the array size.

Comment: I am trying to test this method out now and for some reason something isn't working quite right on it. This is what I have as the resize:

    `public void Resize (int d) {
  T[] temp = (T[]) Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), d);
  System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, 0, size);
  array = temp;
 }`

and the arrays that I create of String and Random are for some reason not initialized to the default size I have in my constructor, and it will not let me resize them either, any ideas?

Comment: @xTopShelfx What's the issue? Not working is not enough description of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, kept hitting "enter" before finishing the comment, my bad!

Comment: @xTopShelfx Can you update your question with exact issue. You still haven't given enough desription. Is there any exception, or any unexpected behaviour? Jot that down on your question itself. It will be easier to read.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47090/discussion-between-xtopshelfx-and-rohit-jain)

Comment: @xTopShelfx Where does the `size` variable comes from? Anyways, you have initialized the size, but you haven't initialized the array there. You need to do that. 0-arg constructor wouldn't be helpful here, as you won't know the `Class<T>` for array.